# problems running npx expo start

Tags: node.js, expo, node-modules

```
i'm trying to start a project using "npx expo start" but i'm getting the same error, i don't know how to solve it. This error started after the new expo update to SDK 46, I already tried to start new projects following the documentation step-by-step, but I keep getting the same error. My operating system is linux.

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (node:fs:748:3)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:448:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:494:19)
    at readPackageJSON (/home/ronaldfleetss/expo2/my-app/node_modules/find-yarn-workspace-root/index.js:50:26)
    at findWorkspaceRoot (/home/ronaldfleetss/expo2/my-app/node_modules/find-yarn-workspace-root/index.js:23:22)
    at getWorkspaceRoot (/home/ronaldfleetss/expo2/my-app/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/getModulesPaths.js:34:49)
    at getWatchFolders (/home/ronaldfleetss/expo2/my-app/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/getWatchFolders.js:124:65)
    at getDefaultConfig (/home/ronaldfleetss/expo2/my-app/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js:253:63)
    at Object.loadAsync (/home/ronaldfleetss/expo2/my-app/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js:352:23)
    at Object.instantiateMetroAsync (/home/ronaldfleetss/expo2/my-app/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/metro/instantiateMetro.js:27:45)

I need help, I've tried to make several changes in the application, I've also tried to enter the node's default folder and give all possible permissions, but I don't know if the error is in the expo or in nodejs.
```

making some observations I've already uninstalled the global expo, I've also made changes to the package.json as requested in the expo documentation. I've also tried running npm install to update the new changes, but with no success.